# Artifacts when using fill_between and backend_pdf and turning off autoscale

Tags: python, linux, pdf, matplotlib

I have a function which plots an estimation error over time (a line) and the covariance of that estimate (a filled region). Sometimes the estimation error is several orders of magnitude smaller than the covariance, so I have the function set up to automatically scale the y limits to emphasize the estimation error.

The function works fine when I plot it to the screen with `plt.show()`, but when I try to plot it to a PDF using the `backend_pdf` module of matplotlib, I get weird visual artifacts.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf as plt_pdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

P =      np.array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.13438020e-02,   7.09875882e-03,
                     5.22532652e-03,   3.98620107e-03,   3.16986671e-03,
                     2.61435852e-03,   2.21858461e-03,   1.92450926e-03,
                     1.69821798e-03,   1.51903818e-03,   1.37380019e-03,
                     1.25377026e-03,   1.15294938e-03,   1.06708988e-03,
                     9.93104161e-04,   9.28696130e-04,   8.72123940e-04,
                     8.22042891e-04,   7.77398690e-04,   7.37353271e-04,
                     7.01232187e-04,   6.68486622e-04,   6.38665488e-04,
                     6.11394634e-04,   5.86361140e-04,   5.63301300e-04,
                     5.41991330e-04,   5.22240095e-04,   5.03883377e-04,
                     4.86779303e-04,   4.70804678e-04,   4.55852012e-04,
                     4.41827103e-04,   4.28647046e-04,   4.16238597e-04,
                     4.04536807e-04,   3.93483885e-04,   3.83028239e-04,
                     3.73123673e-04,   3.63728701e-04,   3.54805964e-04,
                     3.46321733e-04,   3.38245478e-04,   3.30549503e-04,
                     3.23208626e-04,   3.16199899e-04,   3.09502370e-04,
                     3.03096873e-04,   2.96965838e-04,   2.91093134e-04,
                     2.85463925e-04,   2.80064539e-04,   2.74882362e-04,
                     2.69905735e-04,   2.65123865e-04,   2.60526748e-04,
                     2.56105095e-04,   2.51850271e-04,   2.47754238e-04,
                     2.43809500e-04,   2.40009062e-04,   2.36346383e-04,
                     2.32815343e-04,   2.29410201e-04,   2.26125572e-04])
x = np.ones(P.shape) * 1e-13
t = np.arange(0,x.shape[0])

pdf = plt_pdf.PdfPages('plot_mwe.pdf')
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.fill_between(t, P, -P)
ax.plot(t, x, c='black')
ax.set_ylim(bottom = -1.5e-13, top = 1.5e-13, auto = False)

pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()

plt.show()
```

This code produces the following pdf:
[image: plot_mwe backend_pdf]

However, what I'd expect to see is this one:
[image: plot_mwe pyplot]

I'm thinking this is a bug, but wondered if anyone knew of a workaround. Why is this happening? (I guess I can just change the values of `P` so they fit the plot ylimits perfectly, but that makes me nervous, since it introduces new sources of error.)

**UPDATE:** People have commented that this doesn't happen in Windows. I've tried Atril and Evince (two Linux PDF viewers), and it's the same in both. My system is `Linux axiom-dev 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

**UPDATE #2:** The generated PDF is problematic on multiple operating systems. Below you can see Mac's built-in Preview app rendering the `fill_between` area in the page thumbnail, but not on the page itself. It seems to be a bug with `backend_pdf`, not with the viewers.

[image: Mac Preview also struggles with the generated PDF.]

Comment: I tried running your example, and the PDF looks the same as the figure when I open it (Adobe Acrobat, Windows 10), not like your PDF screenshot. What PDF reader are you using? Have you tried opening in different ones?

Comment: I don't even understand the problem to be honest. What exactly is wrong with the output?

Comment: @whrrgarbl Looks like it's Linux specific. Thanks for testing on Windows for me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It should be filling between two lines (-P, P). Those lines are relatively flat and they're well outside the y-limits. In other words, there shouldn't be any vertical blue and white banding — it should just be blue, as in the second figure.

Comment: I edited the question, It was only two lines I was missing- but with great impact. I can also only test on windows and its looking as expected. But you would probably still want to test if it is really a wrong pdf being produced or if the pdf is simply not shown correctly. Maybe you can send the pdf to someone with a windows acrobar reader to test?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried the PDF on Mac, and the artifacts aren't the same, but it's still having trouble rendering the `fill_between`.